# Sorting columns by column sum in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframes that has column names like that. each column has binary values

```
"TP53"     "TRRAP"    "TSC1"     "TYRO3"    "U2AF1"    "ZFP36L1"  "ZNRF3"    "1p34.2"   "1q21.1"   "1q23.2"
```

I am trying to sort the columns based on column sum by

```
dfsort<-df[,names(sort(colSums(df), decreasing = TRUE))]
```

but the dfsort only got columns  `"TP53"     "TRRAP"    "TSC1"     "TYRO3"    "U2AF1"    "ZFP36L1"  "ZNRF3"`  while column names starting with numbers are not in the output. what is wrong?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example data:

```
variable_names <- c("TP53", "TRRAP", "TSC1", "TYRO3", "U2AF1", "ZFP36L1", "ZNRF3", "1p34.2", "1q21.1", "1q23.2")

num_observations <- 10

df <- data.frame(
  sapply(variable_names, function(variable) sample(0:1, num_observations, replace = TRUE))
)

print(df)

> print(df)
   TP53 TRRAP TSC1 TYRO3 U2AF1 ZFP36L1 ZNRF3 X1p34.2 X1q21.1 X1q23.2
1     1     1    0     0     1       0     0       1       1       0
2     1     0    0     0     0       1     1       1       0       1
3     1     1    1     0     1       0     1       0       1       0
4     0     0    1     1     0       1     0       0       1       1
5     1     0    1     1     0       1     0       1       1       0
6     1     0    1     1     0       1     0       1       0       1
7     1     0    0     0     0       1     1       1       1       1
8     1     0    1     1     0       1     1       1       0       1
9     0     0    1     1     0       1     0       1       0       0
10    1     0    1     0     0       1     0       1       1       1
```

If you want to sort by sum:

```
df_sorted <- df[, order(-colSums(df))]

> print(df_sorted)
   TP53 ZFP36L1 X1p34.2 TSC1 X1q21.1 X1q23.2 TYRO3 ZNRF3 TRRAP U2AF1
1     1       0       1    0       1       0     0     0     1     1
2     1       1       1    0       0       1     0     1     0     0
3     1       0       0    1       1       0     0     1     1     1
4     0       1       0    1       1       1     1     0     0     0
5     1       1       1    1       1       0     1     0     0     0
6     1       1       1    1       0       1     1     0     0     0
7     1       1       1    0       1       1     0     1     0     0
8     1       1       1    1       0       1     1     1     0     0
9     0       1       1    1       0       0     1     0     0     0
10    1       1       1    1       1       1     0     0     0     0
```